# Cookies are not stored on client side in MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies, mern

I want to store the jwt token as a cookie from express.js(backend) to react.js(frontend). I also installed the `cookie-parser` package and use it in the main.js file(server-side) and create the cookies by using `res.cookies`. if I try with the postman, the postman shows cookies generate successfully but if I try with the react then cookies are not stored.

**express code:**

```
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // geting the user email and the password

    const { userEmail, userPass } = req.body;

    // 1st we are checking that email and the password are existing
    if (!userEmail || !userPass) {
      return next("Plz enter valid email and password");
    }
    console.log(userEmail, userPass);
    // 2nd if usre is existing than password is correct or not

    const user = await userModel.findOne({ userEmail }).select("+password");
    const correct = await user.correctPassword(userPass, user.password);
    if (!userEmail || !correct) {
      return next("Wrong credentials");
    }
    // 3rd if everything is ok then we send the token to the client

    const userToken = signToken(user._id);
    // here we passing the token by using cookie
    res.cookie("jwt", userToken, {
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 500000),
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
    });
    // console.log(userToken);

    res.status(200).json({
      status: " successfully Login",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      data: next(error),
    });
  }
};
```

**React code is here:**

```
const Login = () => {
  const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState({
    userEmail: "",
    userPass: "",
  });

  let name, value;
  const handelInputs = (e) => {
    name = e.target.name;
    value = e.target.value;
    setUserLogin({ ...userLogin, [name]: value });
  };

  const log = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post("/login", userLogin, {
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: "include",
    })
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it's only sent to the server. For example, cookies that persist in server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Simply change

```
httpOnly: true
```

to

```
httpOnly: false
```